# How do you clone an object in Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, clone

I keep seeing terms like "shallow copy" and "deep copy," and I don't understand those one bit; could someone please help me with cloning an object (in my case, a simple button) and placing it on the form?

- Using code, not in the object interface
- This is in VB.net I'm *pretty sure.*

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You should specify which language (and GUI framework) you're asking about.  What have you tried/learned thus far?  Also see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy).

Comment: What about cloning objects in IDEs other than Visual Studio?

Comment: What is that? Sorry, I'm not *too* good at VB! :P

Comment: If you are using VS 2008 or VS 2010, you are **NOT** doing VB6.  You are doing VB.NET.

Comment: If all you want is to clone a button, just copy/paste it in the IDE